# Is an Xcode project for the Mac Bitcoin client available?

Tags: client, development, mac

If someone wants to mod the Mac Bitcoin client for their own purposes (e.g. reskinning or development of a client with extra features), is there somewhere they could download the existing Xcode project for the software to get started quickly? If not, why is it not available?

Comment: You might want to start with a GitHub fork of MultiBit (which has a dedicated Mac installer): http://multibit.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe the project itself is distributed, but there is a [step-by-step guide](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/793/what-are-the-steps-in-building-bitcoind-on-mac-os-x-10-6/1314#1314) to creating an Xcode project for Bitcoin in the answers to "[What are the steps in building bitcoind on Mac OS X 10.6?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/793/what-are-the-steps-in-building-bitcoind-on-mac-os-x-10-6)"