# Accesing bitcoind through terminal on mac

Tags: bitcoind, mac

How do I use bitcoind through Terminal on Mac OSX? I think this is not adressed by these questions, but honestly, I'm not sure:

[Bitcoin-Qt command line control on Mac](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2570/bitcoin-qt-command-line-control-on-mac)

[What are the steps in building bitcoind on Mac OS X 10.6?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/793/what-are-the-steps-in-building-bitcoind-on-mac-os-x-10-6)

Answer (score 1):

Per Gavin Andresen's answer on the first post to which you linked, Bitcoin-Qt for Mac [does not ship with bitcoind](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/2612/1409). However, you can still access it with `curl` or `wget`, or using the provided Python wrapper. See the post for more.

If you are adamant about using `bitcoind` itself, your best bet is to compile your own `bitcoind` using [my instructions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5253/1409) or using the [instructions provided in the source distribution of bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md).

Comment: The OSX build instructions mentioned above may be one in the same come 0.8.0, when [issue #2026](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/2026) is complete.